# Data Migration Tool interrumpted, and know I can´t start again

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool

I have a problem running Data Migration Tool to migrate a Magento 1.7.0.2 to Magento 2.2. I run the command:

```
php bin/magento migrate:data -r vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.7.0.2/config.xml -vvvv
```

And it shows the progress, but stayed in **EAV Setup**:

```
[2018-01-25 22:14:55][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Data Integrity Step]: started 
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec 
[2018-01-25 22:14:55][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: EAV Step]: started 
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec 
[2018-01-25 22:14:55][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Customer Attributes Step]: started 
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec 
[2018-01-25 22:14:55][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Map Step]: started 
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec 
[2018-01-25 22:14:57][WARNING]: Mismatch of data types. Destination document: testimonial. Fields: content 
[2018-01-25 22:14:57][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Url Rewrite Step]: started 
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec 
[2018-01-25 22:14:57][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Log Step]: started 
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec 
[2018-01-25 22:14:57][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Ratings Step]: started 
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec 
[2018-01-25 22:14:57][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: ConfigurablePrices step]: started 
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec 
[2018-01-25 22:14:57][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: OrderGrids Step]: started 
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec 
[2018-01-25 22:14:57][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Tier Price Step]: started 
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec 
[2018-01-25 22:14:57][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: SalesIncrement Step]: started 
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec 
[2018-01-25 22:14:57][INFO][mode: data][stage: setup triggers][step: Stage]: started 
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec 
[2018-01-25 22:14:59][INFO][mode: data][stage: data migration][step: EAV Step]: started 
28% [========>-------------------] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
```

And stayed there for a very long time (one hour or more), and the percentage did not change.. So, in my despair, I canceled the command and ran the command again. But when I did it, the screen only shows the ***Reset the current position of migration to start from the beginning*** message and nothing more. Stay in that form for hours again, and nothing happens.

What could I do to run the migration again successfully?

Thanks.

Comment: migration takes long time , its ok! check migration log. you must have database backup.

Comment: @MagenX at the end I did that, restore database and run again. I see some errors of max_allowed_packets but after increase the value, the migration runs fine. Thanks.